# Graph of Chebyshev's first polynomials, almost like the wikipedia graph

Tags: plotting, special-functions, legending

I want to graph the first polynomials of Chebyshev almost like [the graph of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chebyshev_Polynomials_of_the_First_Kind.svg):

[image: Chebyshev polynomials]

I have tried it this way

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[ChebyshevT[n - 1, x], {n, 5}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Green, Magenta, Purple}, 
PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Green, Magenta, 
Purple},{"T0","T1","T2","T3","T4"}]
```

I can't put the legends on top of the graphic like in wikipedia or at least put them in a single line.

I have tried with the Show command but I have not succeeded. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you seen that the source Mathematica code is actually on the wikipedia image page that you linked to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** A more streamlined version

```
Plot[Evaluate@ChebyshevT[Range[0, 4], x], {x, -1, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Green, Magenta, Purple}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"T0", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"}], Top]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[ChebyshevT[n - 1, x], {n, 5}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Green, Magenta, Purple}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Green, Magenta, Purple}, {"T0", "T1", 
     "T2", "T3", "T4"}], Top]]
```

[image]

Also

```
Legended[Plot[Evaluate[Table[ChebyshevT[n - 1, x], {n, 5}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Green, Magenta, Purple}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific"], Placed[
  LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Green, Magenta, Purple}, {"T0", "T1", 
    "T2", "T3", "T4"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}], Top]]
```

> same picture

Comment: With a few bells: `Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[Tooltip[ChebyshevT[n, x]], {n, 0, 4}],
 {x, -1, 1},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, ChebyshevT[n, x]}),
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[Table[Subscript[T, n], {n, 0, 5}], Top]]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight refactoring of the [Wikipedia code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chebyshev_Polynomials_of_the_First_Kind.svg) for the image:

```
Inactive[Plot][
  Table[Inactive[ChebyshevT][n, x], {n, 0, 4}],
  {x, -1, 1},
  Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Dashed], Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend["Expressions", LegendMargins -> 0, 
     LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}], Top], ImageSize -> 700] // Activate
```

[image]

The legend labels have the default tooltips that show that $T$ stands for `ChebyshevT`.  The key is using `Inactive` to allow some parts of the code to evaluate (e.g. `Table[]`) but prevent other parts not to evaluate (e.g. `ChebyshevT[0, x]` etc.).  When the plotting code is ready, the final `Activate` lets it run.